# A necessary and sufficient condition for a full lattice over an integral domain

Tags: commutative-algebra, algebraic-number-theory

I'm learning about lattices over integral domains and I would be grateful if someone could clarify the following for me.

Let $R$ be an integral domain with quotient field $K$ where $K\neq R$. Suppose we have an $R$ -lattice $M$, i.e. a finitely generated torsion free $R$-module and a finite dimensional $K$-vector space $V$.

Is it true that $K\otimes_{R}M=V$ if and only if $M$ contains a $K$-basis of $V$?

I know that since $M$ is $R$-torsion free, it embeds into $V$. Does this imply that $M$ contains a $K$-basis of $V$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$K\otimes_R M=S^{-1}M$, where $S=R-\{0\}$. Since $S^{-1}M=V$, then a basis of $V$ has the form $x_1/1,\dots,x_n/1$ with $x_i\in M$.

Comment: Many thanks for the reply!